# Relationship between Book, Profile and Author in correct or not in Django

Tags: django-models, model, schema

I have created 3 tables profile, author, and book. The relationship between these three tables is correct or not in Django.

from django.db import models

```
# It is a user profile 
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_lenght=250)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    useremail = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
# It is a author table
class Author(models.Model):
    authorname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    authoremail = models.EmailField()
    authormobile = models.IntegerField()
    authoraffliation = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.authorname
# It is a book database 
class Book(models.Model):
    bookname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    bookuser = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    bookauthor = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    published_year = models.DateField()
    isbn_number = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    # The __str__ method just tells django what to print when it need to print out an instance of Book model  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.bookname
```

Comment: It depends on your requirements. Is it a requirement that your user profile is in the books model?

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: (Check the title: there are two `in`s, deviating from one `is` in the body's second sentence.)

Comment: (Your code needs a code block. I find it easy and not error prone to place a line containing just `~~~` before&after.)

Comment: (Depending on use, it may be prohibitively expensive to correct spelling like `affliation` later on.)

Comment: (A book can have many authors, but just one user? *That*'s exclusive. (Over the years, a single *title* may be republished by multiple publishers.))